# Xcode 11.0 build get error - Unknown argument type '__attribute__' in method -[RCTAppState getCurrentAppState:error:]

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

On every build in Xcode i get this error. How can i fix it?

I found this commit https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/25146/commits/61b8b9e69d8609fecaaaa7d2c9e32808bc5e98cb which should fix it but nothing happened.

```
static BOOL RCTParseUnused(const char **input)
{
 return RCTReadString(input, "__unused") ||
     RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((__unused__))") ||
     RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((unused))");
}
```

I have still this error

[image]

Can you help me fix it please?

---

I looked in node_modules and i already have this line

```
static BOOL RCTParseUnused(const char **input)
{
  return RCTReadString(input, "__unused") ||
         RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((__unused__))") ||
         RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((unused))");
}
```

Do you have another advice please?

Comment: 1) did you try clean Xcode build?
2) are you sure fix still in your code? It located in node_modules and will be removed on each `npm install`

Comment: Which version of react native do you have? Versions 0.59.9+ have a fix for this.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The solution is to either Upgrade to RN 59.9 or higher OR to apply [this patch](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/25146/files) manually:

1. go to `node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm`
2. Add the line from the patch.

Comment: Manually didn't work but i updated every package including react-native and now it works :) thank a lot!

Comment: Worked manually here too. We're using pods, so I had to `pod deintegrate; pod install`

Comment: Thanks for this, it was great to find such a clear answer.

Answer (score 38):

Solution for this issue: go to node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm and update below code

```
static BOOL RCTParseUnused(const char **input)
{
  return RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((unused))") ||
           RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((__unused__))") ||
           RCTReadString(input, "__unused");
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Manoj for this great answer! this works!

Comment: @NiroshanJ no worries.

Comment: @RizwanAtta no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Next code work for me:

```
static BOOL RCTParseUnused(const char **input)
{
  return RCTReadString(input, "__unused") ||
         RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((__unused__))") ||
         RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((unused))");
}
```