# Unknown argument type '_Bool' EAzureBlobStorageFile and Exception '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]

Tags: javascript, ios, azure, react-native, azure-blob-storage

The errors

Unknown argument type '_Bool' in method -[EAzureBlobStorageFile configure:key:container:token:]. Extend RCTConvert to support this type.

Exception '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]' was thrown while invoking configure on target EAzureBlobStorageFile with params

and the fix of adding `RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((__unused__))") ||` does not apply as it was already corrected on the version im using, im working on iOS by the way

"react-native": "0.66.4"

"react-native-azure-blob-storage": "^2.0.3",

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

- Based on the [***GitHub***](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/25146/files) issue is the fix is to add the below code(by opening `myproject /node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm`. ) with the upgraded version of [**`react-native`**](https://reactnative.dev/versions) and [**`react-native-azure-blob-storage`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-blob-storage) .

> ***Code:-***
>
> ```
> static BOOL RCTParseUnused(const char **input)
> {
>   return RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((unused))") ||
>          RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((__unused__))") ||
>          RCTReadString(input, "__unused");
> }
> ```

For more information please refer the below links:-

- ***Similar*** [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58051510/xcode-11-0-build-get-error-unknown-argument-type-attribute-in-method-r/58061998#58061998) .
- ***Github solution***|[***XCode 11 Beta App Launch Crash***](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25154) .